# Regex: Excluding tokens that contain only digits

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to get all tokens that aren't only digits - so 'abc' and 'abc7' and '123xyz' are ok but '1234' isn't.

I know you can use

```
\b\d+\b
```

to get just '1234' but when I try adding '^' to the front of that it doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
(?!^\d+$)^.+$
```

This is a negative lookahead, it will exclude all strings that start with digits and end with digits.

If your string start with a letter, it will be excluded as not matching `^\d+`, which means it will be accepted.
If your string ends with a letter, it will be excluded as not matching `\d+$`, which means it will be accepted.
Then the remaining part of the expression (`^.+$`) will match absolutely anything.
If the string is only digits, it will match with the negative-lookahead and not the last part, which means it will return a non-match result.

So basically, only digits strings will not match.

Comment: When I try this using regexr.com, it doesn't seem to match anything

Comment: Which website / langage did you try ? Sometimes there's a few differences with regex expression depending on the langage.

I am trying here https://regex101.com/ and it will work with any langage except Golang because Golang does not recognize the ?

Comment: On RegExr you have to be careful when testing on multiple lines as each entry will not be considered at a single value.
I tested on RegExr and the provided regex works, try it in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4LNQVH/1)):

```
(?!\b\d+\b)\b\S+\b
```

---

This matches all tokens that aren't only digits.